# flink: is it losing records?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

My topology is like this: `kafka(p:6)->reduce(p:6)->db writer(p:12)` (where p: is parallelism).

- I have it running on a single node "cluster" with `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 30`
- I know that my kafka source is producing ~6.5M records / min
- The kafka 'reader' has a parallelism equal to the # of kafka partitions

When I observe this job (via the flink UI) for ~1 min these are the values I'm seeing:

- kafka -> reduce: ~1.5M records sent (off by > 4x)
- reduce (windowed aggregate of 5 seconds) -> db write ~114K records sent (off by > 2x)<sup>1</sup>
- db write --> records received: ~23K (off by > 5x) <sup>2</sup>

(There are smaller discrepancies between the sent / received values for the other parts but I can attribute these to measurement errors)

Question(s):
1. Where are the rest of the records?
2. The load on this machine never gets above 1.5 while this is running. Is there some other limiting factor?
3. Am I misreading the values from the UI?

Java 8
Flink 1.0 (latest github)
Machine: 32 cores / 96 Gb RAM

<sup>1</sup>This one could be explained by the aggregation process.
<sup>2</sup>This value lines up with what got written to the db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flink does not loose records, they are simply buffered in-flight, or they stay longer in Kafka. From the numbers, it looks like you are experiencing **back-pressure**.

You can see that the "reducer" has emitted a lot of records which have not yet been received by the "db writer". In that case these records are still in the buffers of the communication channel between the operators. These channels have a limited amount of buffering (depending on the number of configured buffers, usually a few MBs). For small records, they will probably hold some multiple 10k records.

If the number of sent records in one operator is constantly trailing significantly behind the received records in the receiving operator, this is an indicator that the receiver (here the "db writer") cannot keep up with the data rate. Maybe because the DB is not handling inserts fast enough (too synchronous, too fine grained committing?), maybe the network between the "db writer" and the DB is saturated.

In that case, the "db writer" will backpressure the reducer, which will eventually also backpressure the Kafka Source.

To try out what the data rate would be if you did not have the back pressure from the database, you can try an experiment where the "db writer" simply drops all records.